# Mod or rem. Which one to use with positive integers in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

The `rem` in Haskell behaves just like the `%` in JavaScript. When using the clock analogy `rem` always goes clock-wise regardless if the value is positive or negative. `rem` takes the sign of the divident

```
divident / divisor = quotient

Prelude> 10 `rem` 3
1

Prelude> -10 `rem` 3
-1
```

`%` in JavaScript works the same way

```
$ node

> 10 % 3
  1

> -10 % 3
  -1
```

`mod` behaves like `rem` when both values are positive. The only difference is that when one of the numbers is negative `mod` goes backwards on the clock, not clock-wise and takes the sign of the divisor.

Knowing that `mod` and `rem` give the same result when both numbers are positive which one is recommended to be used in Haskell?

Comment: `mod` is [defined](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Real.html#mod) in terms of `divMod` which is defined in terms of `quotRem`. `rem` is defined in terms of `quotRem`, so it's one less function call.

Comment: Note that ``-10 `rem` 3`` is parsed as ``- (10`rem`3)``. That doesn't actually change the question, but it means ``-10 `mod` 3`` does _also_ give `-1` as the result, whereas ``(-10)`mod`3`` gives `2` as the result.

Comment: Also note that JavaScript inherits this behaviour of `%` from C, which might be more relevant. (Meanwhile, e.g. in Python the `%` operator behaves like Haskell's `mod`.)

Comment: If you know both numbers are positive, use rem since that's what the instruction does on modern processors (I can only remember NS32k providing an instruction for mod as well).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`div` and `mod` are more semantically sensible, while `quot` and `rem` are marginally faster. So my advice is to use `div` and `mod` as a reflex, and only ever change to using `quot` and `rem` after doing a lot of work to make sure their performance is actually relevant to some slowdown you absolutely must fix and doing a lot of work to prove that it's safe. In the long run, subtle sign bugs are almost certainly going to cost you much more debugging time than subtle performance bugs will cost you computation time.

Comment: I agree that `mod` tends to be more semantically sensible, but then again the “subtle sign bugs” should usually be caught right away by QuickCheck whereas subtle performance bugs tend to just never be fixed at all because each of them doesn't make enough difference that anybody would care doing it... whereas a whole lot of such suboptimalities _may_ together make the program quite significantly slower.

Comment: In any event, any change made for performance reasons should be extensively checked via benchmarking.  For example, if the divisor is a known power of two, the native code generator optimizes `div` and `mod` to single shift/and instructions, versus three instructions a piece for `quot` and `rem`.